Can one prevent Google Assistant from calling numbers not in one's contacts?
When asking Google Assistant (on a Samsung Galaxy A54) to call a specified person, if it can't find the contact, it resorts to looking for and automatically dialling a phone number from the internet. This can be wildly incorrect - it has been known to start expensive international calls.
Is there any way to force Google Assistant to restrict its search to the user's contacts?
